# Create list of arguments for function with variable number of inputs

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

My problem: I have written a function which uses the varargin syntax, which is explained [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html). Now I am stuck with the problem how to create a list of arguments which I can pass to this function. The setting is comparable to this:
Say I have a function

`matrixmult(A, varargin)`

which determines the product of arbitrary many matrices with the matrix A. Now I want to determine the product of A with n matrices, where n is set previously in the code. It looks like this:

```
n=4;
A=eye(5);
B=ones(5);
matrixmult(A, ?)
```

What do I have to write instead of ? in order to receive the same result as this:

```
n=4;
A=eye(5);
B=ones(5);
matrixmult(A,B,B,B,B)
```

Google didn't help as variable input always leads to questions about how to use varargin and not how to pass arguments which are created in sort of a loop.
I tried various things such as creating a string ',B' and repeating it several times in order to use eval(string). 
If this should be a duplicate please DO mark it.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place all of the inputs into a cell array and then use the `{:}` syntax to [create a comma-separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) which is then passed as multiple inputs to your function.

So in your case, something like:

```
% Create n copies of B each within it's own cell array element
inputs = repmat({B}, [1 n]);

% Pass all of these B matrices to your function
matrixmult(A, inputs{:});
```